# Git: "not a valid name" when adding local repo as remote repo

Tags: git

I have this situation:

I have two repositories on my machine, both are based on the same original repository.

But the other one has a branch I would like to copy to the other (I created it on that other repo and did lots of changes). Reason for this is that the second repo is in the Eclipse workspace and includes my "current" work.

I have tried creating a remote repo:

```
[remote "other"]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/other/*
url = /home/me/src/other
```

It shows up with git remote:

```
$:~/src/prod$ git remote
other
origin
```

But if I try to access that branch with e.g.

```
git branch --track other_branch other/branch
```

I get

```
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'other/branch'.
```

That branch does exist, I have verified with "git branch".

So what's wrong?

I also tried adding this to .git/config with

```
[branch "branch"]
remote = other
merge = refs/heads/other_branch
```

But the branch won't show up with "git branch -r".

Comment: have you fetched other? `git fetch other`

Comment: Not yet, as I'm not quite sure what would happen. Hm, I'll try that.

Comment: Ah, that actually worked! Silly me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't contacted the remote repository git doesn't know about `other/branch` branch, so it complains about it. Just fetch the repository state with

```
git fetch other
```

Comment: @Makis, note that that fetch refspec `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/other/*` is exactly what Git is supposed to do, when you tell it to fetch from the remote "other": grab all "heads" (branches) the remote has and create them under the "remotes/other" hierarchy, resetting any branch if needed ("+"). Hence once you fetch, you automagically have those "other/*" branches. To better understand how Git resolves these names, read the [`gitrevisions`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/gitrevisions.html) manual.