# facing issue to push local repo to git hub

Tags: java, repository, program-entry-point

I had created a Main folder on desktop and inside that i have 2 sub folders. I created some java programs in IntelliJ in one of the sub folder and committed the programs. When I was trying to push the code to remote but is giving me the following error  "
fatal: remote error: is not a valid repository name. Visit git hub for help."
How should I save it in remote and move further?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find something your local repository doesn't know about.

If you arent sure about your remotes, execute `git remote -v`.

If you got some there you can try to update the status of your local repository by executing `git fetch`

[FUp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10847016/10910433)